# Automation of excel 2010 5 times slower than before

Tags: python, performance, excel, com, automation

We have several programs generating excel documents via com automation, some written in VB6, some in python. Regardless of the programming language those programs run 5 times slower than with older excel versions. Profiling the python version shows that the additional run time is spent mostly in low level com functionality (built-in methods Bind and Invoke), so every single com call is slowed down.

Any tips, how we can speed this up, maybe a (security?) setting in excel 2010?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer for Python, but for VBA/VB6 a significant number of changes were made in XL 2010 to improve performance rather than make it slower, see:
http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/09/03/performance-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx
 Could you give a VB example of something that is 5 times slower in 2010?

Comment: That helped me already, as in order to make a "simple slow program" (inserting 1000 cells in a sheet) I discovered, that this simple program ran as fast with excel 2010 as it does with older versions, so my hypothesis of a general slowdown of automation calls does not hold. More experimentation needed...